# How to add rows with previous values to a table in PostgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I have a table with current levels of our users in PostgreSQL. The problem is I only have current level for each user, when I need to have all previous level for each user for further table transformation.
Now my table looks like:

| user_id | current_level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

When I need it to look like:

| user_id | current_level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

What is the method I can use here to get such result? I assume there should be some window function but not sure which one (all window functions I know are doing different things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE aaa (
    user_id int4 NULL,
    current_level int4 NULL,
);

INSERT INTO aaa (user_id, current_level) VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO aaa (user_id, current_level) VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO aaa (user_id, current_level) VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO aaa (user_id, current_level) VALUES(4, 1);
INSERT INTO aaa (user_id, current_level) VALUES(5, 2);
```

Your query:

```
select user_id, generate_series(1, current_level) from aaa
```

Result:

```
user_id generate_series
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       2
3       3
3       4
4       1
5       1
5       2
```